# Group Observables and then filter by count

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm having trouble filtering an Observable that is based on a `groupBy` observable.

Here is an example based on the `groupBy()` documentation:

```js
var codes = [
  { keyCode: 38}, // up
  { keyCode: 38}, // up
  { keyCode: 40}, // down
  { keyCode: 40}, // down
  { keyCode: 37}, // left
  { keyCode: 39}, // right
  { keyCode: 37}, // left
  { keyCode: 39}, // right
  { keyCode: 66}, // b
  { keyCode: 65}  // a
];

var source = Rx.Observable.from(codes)
  .groupBy(
    function (x) { return x.keyCode; },
    function (x) { return x.keyCode; }
  )
  .flatMap(obs =>
    obs.count()
      .filter(x => x > 1)
      .flatMap(obs.toArray())
  )

source.subscribe(console.log)
```

This returns:

```js
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

So, the Observables are being filtered, but their values are gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tricky to reason about observables as a single object (say, an array) instead of as a asynchronous sequence of values. What happens here is :

- you take the `obs` observable and then you apply `count` to it

  `count` will wait for the observable to finish and will output one value, the number of elements and then finish.
- you filter that value, but then you are applying `toArray` to `obs` which is already finished. That's why you get an empty array.

So the problem here is the same `obs` variable is a different thing at a different time, so you cannot avoid having to reason about time, when you reuse the same variable at different points of your program.

Now, if you want to get the count number out to the `subscribe`, you should be able to directly write `obs.count().filter(x => x > 1).toArray()` instead of what you have right now. `flatMap` accepts promise and arrays in addition to observables as the return value of the selector function :

cf. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md

UPDATE:
with the comments taken into account, this is what I came up with (to be tested) :

```
var source = Rx.Observable
    .from(codes)
    .scan(function ( acc, code ) {
            acc[code] = acc[code] + 1;
            acc.latest = code;
            return acc;
          }, {})
    .filter(function ( acc ) {return acc[acc.latest] > 1;})
    .flatMap(function ( acc ) {return acc[acc.latest] == 2? Rx.Observable.repeat(acc.latest, 2) : Rx.just(acc.latest);})
```

If you can wait to have all the values processed, you can stop the above after the filter and add `.last()`. This will get you the last accumulator with the count of all values. From there you can do what you want.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to get the count number out to the `subscribe` – I need to retain the original observables.

Comment: what do you mean? `obs => obs.toArray()`? but then you loose the count information. What do you want to do?

Comment: `obs.count().filter(x => x > 1).toArray()` returns arrays with the values returned by `count`, but I need the original arrays (i.e., the original observables)

Comment: What I'm looking for is akin to: `[[1,2],[3,4,5]].filter(a => a.length > 2)`

Comment: you mean more like `[[38,38],[40,40], [66]].filter(a => a.length > 2)`? I can't think of any ways to do that simply with the existing operators. Let me think about it for a minute

Comment: I posted a similar answer – I was definitely thinking about this in the wrong way, and using `scan` is the answer. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution similar to [user3743222's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112788/502331)

```js
  var filtered = source
    .flatMap(obs => {
      var accumulated = obs.scan((a,b) => a.concat(b), [])
      return obs
        .scan((a) => a + 1, 0)
        .filter(i => i > 1)
        .withLatestFrom(
          accumulated, 
          (a, b) => Rx.Observable.from(b)
        )
    })
    .flatMap(d => d)
    .subscribe(d => console.log(d))
```